# Python Protocol for De-/Serialization with Shared Generic Types

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, protocols, python-typing

I am writing a protocol that requires conforming classes to provide serializing/deserializing methods `to_config` and `from_config`.

This is my current approach. CV is the group of allowed types in the config.
The idea is to keep the serialization generic but enforce that whatever type is used for serialization equals the type used for serialization. In other words, the return type of implementation of `to_config` must be the type of the value argument for any implementation of `from_config`.

This is my approach (non-functional) below. I think the issue is that CVT and V are valid only within the context of their methods, but I want them to be valid on the Registrable class level.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol, Union, List, Dict
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias

CV: TypeAlias = Union[str, int, float, bool, List['CV'], Dict[str, 'CV']]
CVT = TypeVar('CVT', bound=CV)
V = TypeVar('V')

class Registrable(Protocol):
    
    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls: Type[V], value: CVT) -> V:
       ...

    def to_config(self: V) -> CVT:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's just as simple as obvious: Generics.
For some reason, I read that Protocols don't support generic types. Well, after reading [PEP544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/), they clearly do!

All it needs to make the above example work is to define V and CVT as protocol generics. All it takes is changing `Protocol` to `Protocol[CVT, V]`.

As we use V as the type for self, it should be bound to the Protocol: `V = TypeVar('V', bound='Registrable')`.

Comment: For `from_config` you could also omit the `type[V]` annotation and use [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) as the return type for Python `>=3.11`.

Comment: Great point @DaniilFajnberg. Looks like `V = TypeVar('V', bound='Registrable')` is identical to how `typing.Self` is defined; although I agree, Self is the way to go for future Python versions. Thx for the addition.